# Filtering two arrays with multiple properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

See two arrays below, first we send the repairs array into backend which will then return the failed inserts with limited properties only which I actually have to substring from a bigger failure message to form the array but it basically goes like this:

```
var sentRepairs = [
{id: 12345, car: 'Nissan', Model: 'Almera', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-06'), Modificator: 'User200' },
{id: 12346, car: 'Nissan', Model: 'Almera', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-07'), Modificator: 'User200' },
{id: 12347, car: 'Toyota', Model: 'Corolla', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-09'), Modificator: 'User200' },
{id: 12348, car: 'Toyota', Model: 'Corolla', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-10'), Modificator: 'User200' },
]
```

And here is all the data I can parse from the response rows which are strings.

```
var failedRepairs = [
{ car: 'Toyota', Model: 'Corolla', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-09'),
{ car: 'Nissan', Model: 'Almera', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-07')
];
```

After this I need to make an subarray which would include the cars which had failed repairs. Notice there can be several repairs for the same model. The identifiers I have to work with are car, model and date. Backend doesn't provide me with id which would make this a breeze.

```
 var resultsArrayShouldLookLikeThis = [
 {id: 12346, car: 'Nissan', Model: 'Almera', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-07'), Modificator: 'User200' },
 {id: 12347, car: 'Toyota', Model: 'Corolla', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-09'), Modificator: 'User200' }
 ]
```

As I realized supported by the comments that this looks kinda scummy request so here is what I have resulted as of now with 4 undefined objects as a results as I kinda expected. The helper function return true if it finds matching part in the array and false if not.

```
 var result = sentRepairs.map(function (x) { 
  if (
   helperService.searchArrayByProperty(x.car, failedRepairs, "car") && 
   helperService.searchArrayByProperty(x.Model, failedRepairs, "Model")) {
  return x;
 }
 });
```

Helper function itself, it's not written by me and I know it doesn't actually do comparison between dates but I'm still getting 4 undefined objects even without date comparison:

```
var searchArrayByProperty = function(value, array, property) {
        var item = {};
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (typeof array[i][property] === "string") {
                if (array[i][property].toString() === value) {
                    item = array[i];
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            else if (typeof array[i][property] === "number") {
                if (array[i][property] === value) {
                    item = array[i];
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            else if (typeof array[i][property] === "boolean") {
                if (array[i][property] === value) {
                    item = array[i];
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            else if (typeof array[i][property] === "undefined") {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (found) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post what code you have tried so far?

Comment: We aren't a code writing service.  We are a resource to help you figure out why code you've already tried is not working properly.   For that to work, you have to show us what you've tried.

Comment: Hold on, I know that. I'll update in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` and a loop :

```
resultsArrayShouldLookLikeThis  = sentRepairs.filter(function(item){
    for(var i = 0; i < failedRepairs.length; i++){
        if(JSON.stringify(item.RepairDate) == JSON.stringify(failedRepairs[i].RepairDate)){
          return item;
        }
    }
});
```

I compared dates because it's the uniq key between your both intial arrays.

EDIT : https://jsfiddle.net/u39nubpd/1/

I've added additionnal conditions

Comment: This is what my brain was looking for but I just couldn't get it out. I wish I could accept other answers also since they also solved the problem but this is the simplest. Thank you all.

Comment: it filters only by repair date.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate throu `failedRepairs` and build a temporary object, which is used in the filter loop for lookup. Complexity O(n + m).

```js
var sentRepairs = [{ id: 12345, car: 'Nissan', Model: 'Almera', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-06'), Modificator: 'User200' }, { id: 12346, car: 'Nissan', Model: 'Almera', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-07'), Modificator: 'User200' }, { id: 12347, car: 'Toyota', Model: 'Corolla', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-09'), Modificator: 'User200' }, { id: 12348, car: 'Toyota', Model: 'Corolla', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-10'), Modificator: 'User200' }, ],
    failedRepairs = [{ car: 'Toyota', Model: 'Corolla', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-09') }, { car: 'Nissan', Model: 'Almera', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-07') }],
    filtered = function (base, faild) {
        function key(o) { return [o.car, o.Model, o.RepairDate].join('|'); }

        var object = {};

        faild.forEach(function (a) {
            object[key(a)] = true;
        });
        return base.filter(function (a) {
            return object[key(a)];
        });
    }(sentRepairs, failedRepairs);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Hey, seems like a sophisticated solution but I found just using the filter function more efficient for my situation. I definitely learned a new way to approach the problem from this, thanks for the time you put into helping out.

Comment: yes I know, but I meant just simply using the filter function to iterate through failures with for-loop. As in the answer by Durendal.

Answer (score 1):

lodash is a utility that was made for tasks like this:

```
var res = _.intersectionWith(sentRepairs,failedRepairs, function(sentItem, failedItem){
        if(sentItem.car == failedItem.car && sentItem.Model && JSON.stringify(sentItem.RepairDate) == JSON.stringify(failedItem.RepairDate)){
       return sentItem;
    }
});

console.log(res);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7Lmgx0p/)

Comment: Thank you, I was definitely sure there was tools for this issue. I'll be taking a look into lodash.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution 
I may have interpreted the question differently but i think the variable name will help you to understand my point of view.

```
var initislRequestToBackend = [
{ id: 12345, car: 'Nissan', Model: 'Almera', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-06'), Modificator: 'User200' },
{ id: 12346, car: 'Nissan', Model: 'Almera', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-07'), Modificator: 'User200' },
{ id: 12347, car: 'Toyota', Model: 'Corolla', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-09'), Modificator: 'User200' },
{ id: 12348, car: 'Toyota', Model: 'Corolla', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-09'), Modificator: 'User200' },
{ id: 12348, car: 'Toyota', Model: 'Corolla', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-10'), Modificator: 'User200' }];
```

//

```
var backendResponse = [{ car: 'Toyota', Model: 'Corolla', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-09') },
{ car: 'Nissan', Model: 'Almera', RepairDate: new Date('2016-04-07') }];
```

//

```
var messageToShow = _.chain(backendResponse)
.reduce(function(output, val) {
    output.push(_.filter(initislRequestToBackend, val));
    return output;
}, [])
.flatten()
.value();
console.log(messageToShow);
```